# Plot in matlab xlabel with variables

Tags: matlab, plot

I m trying to give my images with no axis a xlabel with variabels. Is there a trick?

```
         figure(678)
         subplot(3,3,1)
         imagesc(image{1,1})
         title(' Image of all images')
         axis image;
         axis off;
         str = sprintf('SSIM = %f, number of bins = %f',variabel1, size(images{1,1},3));
         xlabel('str');
         subplot(3,3,2)
         ...
```

1) is there an easy way?

2) Then I would like to know if I can produce many different subplots like this in an easy way? I would like to have 10*10 images and not only 3*3.

3) Can I change the size between the images? I know I can do it manually after compiling but then the size of the images changes too.

Comment: Just an advice here (on my phone so can't really answer): don't use "image" as a variable name as it is a built-in function and can lead to unexpected behavior

Comment: I changed the name here in my file its not like that, but thanks :)

Comment: Actually I'm not sure to understand the question. Wouldn't a for-loop work in this case?

Comment: you mean for question2? I didn't get a for loop working with imagesc (struc)

My main question is, why the string is not showing. What m I doing wrong?

Comment: The reason why you do not see the x-label is that the function call `axis off;` hides not only the axis but also the ticks and label for the axis. So if you want to use the `xlabel`-function to show the label, you need to remove the `axis off;` line. I would suggest that you try using the `text`-function instead of the `xlabel`-function, since this does not rely on the axes object being visible!

Comment: yes, I need axis off because I don't want them. Thanks, I use text then

Comment: is there an easy way to get the text always at the position of the xlabel?

Comment: I  have now:
ylim=get(gca,'YLim');
text(1,ylim(2)+40,sprintf('SSIM = %f \nnumber of bins = %f',variabel1, size(images{1,1},3)'))